# How can I unit test uniqueness of a Randomly Generated UserID

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I am working on a simple requirement of a UniqueId provider which has the following constraints:

1. Usernames have a prefix of “user”
2. The Ids are comprised of numbers and lowercase alpha
3. ***The Id must be unique across all pre-existing ids in a Member table***
4. The Ids are 10 characters long excluding the prefix

Now my question is in order to test the 3rd point related to Unique User Names across pre-existing ids, can I just generate a random set of Id's lets say 20 or 50 and assert that they are all unique?

I am just not convinced that this test alone will make sure the Uniqueness Algorithm will generate unique id's across 1,00,000 generated id's.

Just a note I need to come up with tests first as following TDD.

Comment: I don't think unit tests are the right tool for testing randomness. A unit test is supposed to call a method and test the returned value against an expected result. The problem with testing randomness is that there isn't an expected value for most of the things you'd like to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Testing [pseudo-]random number generators is...hard. Some resources on the topic.

- http://csrc.nist.gov/groups/ST/toolkit/rng/documents/nissc-paper.pdf
- https://www.random.org/analysis/
- http://www.drdobbs.com/testing-random-number-generators/184403185
- http://www.johndcook.com/blog/2010/12/06/how-to-test-a-random-number-generator-2/
- http://www.johndcook.com/Beautiful_Testing_ch10.pdf
- http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Randomness_tests

But, why not just use the system-provided stuff to gete you where you want to go?

Presumably, your data is stored in a database.

Most databases provide facilities to generate sequential id numebers that are unique. You could use that.

Generating a GUID is pretty unique and easy either in C# or in SQL (usually).

Note that the domain of your user id is 36<sup>10</sup> (0 – 3,656,158,440,062,975): you'll want to get 64 bits worth, convert it to a long and take it modulo 36<sup>10</sup> to get your user id.

You could also, compute a cryptographic hash of the [salted] user data and do the same thing.

In any event, you'll need to code so that you handle the case of a duplicate id being generated.

Answer (score 4):

Consider separating "uniqueness" check (i.e. as separate object) and testing it separately - this way you can easily test for "randomly generated number is already used" by mocking "IsUnique" check.

Than for testing uniqueness check - feed known to be non-unique values (may need to mock what "set of known values" is) and make sure it properly fails.

Note that using "random" to find unique Id may get dangerously slow if number of existing items is comparable to number of all choices (i.e. not acceptable for "shuffle deck of card"). Auto-increment numbers/DB fields are easier to implement/proof for correctness.

Answer (score 2):

Based on long it takes to compute the random ID, you can just verify that for `n` (`n` being close to 1,000,000) they are all unique. 20 or 50 it is not enough to ensure uniqueness of 1 in a 1,000,000.

To actually test this, you can keep track of previous calls to the `Randomizer` and assert that every new ID is not duplicated by any of the previous ones.

Furthermore, it seems like you might as well just use a [`GUID`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx).

Comment: GUIDs won't work due to the `The Ids are 10 characters long excluding the prefix` requirement

Comment: No, but a sequence with base 36 encoding would work.  Also, n being `36^^6 - 1`.